Transition for changing text on a website
On my website I have a part for showing some data. This is hooked up to a button to load other data when pressed. The elements stay the same, but the text inside the spans is changed to show the data. I've noticed that just changing the texts and numbers looks a little boring, so I was looking for something like an animation for changing the text. Something like the CSS transition argument, but for changing text. From my own research I did not find anything suiting my needs, maybe one of you has some code to share. I have in mind something like the text going away to the side with the new text coming in from the other side. Hard to explain what I mean, without having something to show.
Here is a rough example of how I currently replace the text with jquery:
$("#span-1").text("new text");

I tried creating a new class, giving it the transition property and on text change, change the class of the element, then change the text and change back the class after a timeout for the transition, but the text still changed immediatly.
CSS:
.text {
    transition: all 1s ease;
    /* other properties */
}

.text-transition {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

JS:
$("#span-1").text("New Text");
$("#span-1").removeClass("text");
$("#span-1").addClass("text-transition");
setTimeout(() => {
    $("#span-1").removeClass("text-transition");
    $("#span-1").addClass("text");
}, 1000);

This is roughly what I tried, I also tried switching around the orders a bit, you get the idea.

What exactly do you want the animation to do?

@SamSabin Nothing particular in Mind, just something to make it look a bit more smooth

Coding is hard enough when you know what you want, let alone when you don't :)
I'm sure there are many Stack Overflow users happy to take a crack at things, but we need to know what you have in mind, as well as some code with how you're implementing things currently.

@SamSabin I edited the post and added some code, but it's hard to describe what I am looking for, if I can't find what I want on google... I hope you kind of understand what I mean.

@Loki Don't worry, I've got a good understanding of what you're looking for, and I'll give it a try to achieve it.

Have a good think about what effect you want, then have a go at coding it and if still stuck update your question with a description of what required , the code you’ve tried, what debugging you’ve done.

Voting to close as the problem is currently ill defined and people are putting up answers which are just guesses.

My <marquee> answer is the best whatsoever.

Still not 100% sure what you're looking for, but here's one approach:


.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.original-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.new-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.container:hover > .original-text {
  left: -100%;
}

.container:hover > .new-text {
  left: 0px;
}
<div class="container" style="display: flex; position: relative; width: 100px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="original-text">Original Text</div>
    <div class="new-text">New Text</div>
</div>



In this example I have static text and the class transition is loaded on hover, but you can update it so that when the data is loaded you could set the text of the .new-text div to that loaded data, and then you could update the left value directly or add a class that has that info. Alternatively you could add another wrapper div around the original-text and new-text divs and set the left transition on that wrapper instead of original-text and new-text divs, so that you only need to update class for one element (with the downside being that the DOM has an extra element.)
Let me know if this is what you had in mind, or if there are adjustments you were looking at.


Created an array of texts: const texts = ["Old Text", "First New Text", "Second New Text", "Third New Text"];.
Tracked the current text index: let currentIndex = 0;.
On button click:

Fade out the current text by adding a fade-out class.
After the transition, updated the text to the next in the array: span.textContent = texts[currentIndex];.
Incremented the index with wrapping: currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % texts.length;.
Fade in the new text by removing the fade-out class.





const texts = ["Old Text", "First New Text", "Second New Text", "Third New Text"];
let currentIndex = 0;

const loadTextBtn = document.getElementById('loadText');

loadTextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const span = document.getElementById('span-1');

    span.classList.add('fade-out');

    setTimeout(() => {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % texts.length;

        span.textContent = texts[currentIndex];

        span.classList.remove('fade-out');
    }, 1000);
});
.text {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>New Text Animation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <span id="span-1" class="text">Old Text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="loadText" type="button">Get New Text</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




Might consider wrapping the current text, sliding that out of view, and at the same time, sliding in new text.


$(function() {
  function addText(el, newText) {
    var right = $(window).width();
    $(el).css("width", (right - 20) + "px");
    var oldTextElem = $("<span>").css("width", right + "px").html($(el).text().trim());
    $(el).html(oldTextElem);
    var newTextElem = $("<span>").html(newText).insertAfter(oldTextElem);
    oldTextElem.animate({
      marginLeft: "-" + right + "px"
    }, 1750, function() {
      oldTextElem.remove();
    });
  }

  var i = 1;

  $("button").click(function() {
    addText($(".news"), "New Header " + i++);
  });
});
.news {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.news>span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">Title Text</div>
<div class="news">This is the news text.</div>
<button>Load News</button>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>




Nobody asked for Jquery.

@NVRM can't argue with you on that. No one specifically "asked for jQuery". I did notice that OP used jQuery in his post and tagged the post with jQuery.
